# Why has this post been put 'on hold'?

Tags: discussion, question-closure

My question [Why is 'weird' given a sexual connotation nowadays?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214594/why-is-weird-given-a-sexual-connotation-nowadays), has been put on hold as 'off topic', for the reason that 'it is not about the English language'.

Since it queries the current nuance placed on the word 'weird', it seems to me directly to concern the 'English language'.

It did, for reasons best know to the commenters, attract some vehement, forthright, and at times childish responses. But it would appear to me to relate entirely to a matter of current vocabulary.

Comment: 'Off-topic' has a broad range here. Because the question presumes something that many find untrue, it is logically unanswerable and so off-topic because out of scope for a strict question/answer site. Of course it is on topic because it is about the connotations of an English word. It's just too discussiony. And closing is a fun button to press. People are exercizing their rights!! Also Winter Hats!!

Comment: I'm sorry, the 'Winter Hats' is lost on me?

Comment: [Watch the snowfall](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) They spent godless amounts of programmer time getting that one small feature to work right.

Comment: It may very well still be lost on you, but the very fact of my responding at this moment in this manner just got me a Winter Hat. a delectable Winter Hat!

Comment: @Mitch Where do we get to see your winter hat?

Comment: people are downvoting, upvoting, closing, reopening more than usual becaue they want to earn their Xmas/winter hats. If you visit your profile page you should have earned a couple yourself, even without knowing it. However, some users do tend to get overexcited by the chase, most of the deeds to accomplish are "good" ones.

Comment: The hats are like rewarding children for cleaning out their toybox! :-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yippee!

Comment: @WS2 I would say you should go put a hat on, but it appears you are already wearing a real hat....

Comment: @KristinaLopez yay! Toys!!

Comment: @Hellion An old advertising line from circa 1960 Britain went 'If you want to get ahead get a hat'. Since then I have always been for hats. But I gave up party hats when I was 9.

Comment: @KristinaLopez You would be lucky to get away with giving my grandchildren a 'hat'. They'd expect tea at the Ritz. (Well, at the Kosy Korner Kafe anyway)

Comment: @Mitch - what hat did it give you? (I hope to find out shortly.)

Comment: @medica it was supposed to be a hat for just using the SE iPhone app.

Comment: As a programmer, I can't understand why they'd have more than one person working on snow for more than a couple of days. Doesn't StackExchange have a number of other tasks that require programming attention?